# tale of two DRF posts, one works and one not

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

Building vue.js gui for a django application, I have two .vue pages one post for adding a new client that is working and one for adding a new clientaccount that is not working.  They appear to be identical except for the fields.

First the one that is working.

The addNewClient method.

```
// POST API FOR ADDING client
                console.log(this.addNewClient)
                getAPI.post('http://localhost:8000/api/client/', this.addNewClient)
                .then(res=>{
```

and the console.log when posing.

```
submitNewClient
ClientMX.vue:210 Proxy(Object) {clientName: 'Bill Barclay', clientEmail: 'bill@barclay.com', clientPhone: '1234567890', clientCompany: 'Barclay Industries'}
mixins.js:130 --mixins toggleModal(addClientModal)
```

Everything works fine.

Now the addnewClientAccunts method

```
console.log(this.addNewclientAccount)
                getAPI.post('http://localhost:8000/api/clientaccount/', this.addNewClientAccount)
```

and the associated console.log

```
submitNewClientAccount
ClientAccounts.vue:284 Proxy(Object) {client_fk: 28, client_platform: 'FBU', client_key: 'test', client_value: '123456'}
xhr.js:187     POST http://localhost:8000/api/clientaccount/ 400 (Bad Request)
```

The serializers are virtually the same...

```
class ClientAccountsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ClientAccounts
        fields = ('id', 'client_fk', 'client_platform', 'client_key', 'client_value' )
        
        extra_kwargs = {
            'id': {'read_only': True},  # ID is usually read-only
        }
         
        def create(self, validated_data):
            logger.info("ClientAccountsSerializer.create validated_data = %s ", validated_data)
            return ClientAccounts.objects.create(**validated_data)

class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id', 'clientName', 'clientEmail', 'clientPhone', 'clientCompany')

        extra_kwargs = {
            'id': {'read_only': True},  # ID is usually read-only
        }
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        logger.info("ClientSerializer.create validated_data = %s ", validated_data)
        return Client.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

The views are also virtually the same...

```
 def post(self, request):
        print("Client post request.data = %s ", request.data)
        serializer = ClientSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and

```
 def post(self, request):
        print("ClientAccounts post request.data = %s ", request.data)
        serializer = ClientAccountsSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The Client post terminal shows request data with the json record for new client.  the ClientAccounts request data is empty.

The only difference between the two is in the fields.  The two models have different fields, but only the one that is failing has a foreign key.

It is probably something simple I am missing but I have checked and double checked names and cases but the data going out seems correct and only the client post is working.

Answer (score 0):

ok solved, my bad after at least two hours of looking at it I used compare and found the Upper case C in one and lower case c in the other.  Made them the same and bingo we have a winner.